# Swapping Text in <button> on :onclick with plain HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

As simply as topic. I'm looking the way to change text inside button after user click on it, with no usage of JS etc.
Thanks!

Comment: must it be `<button>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED.

If button element is required you can try with ::after pseudo selector. But it will be a bit buggy.

Example.

```
button:after{
   content: 'some content';
   display: block;
}
button:hover:after,
button:focus:after,
button:active:after{
   content: 'some other content';
   display: block;
}
```

**If button element is not required there is another solution.**

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]{
   display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:after {
   content: 'some content';
   display: block;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
   content: 'some other content';
   display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="hidden-input" name="hidden-input"> 
 <label for="hidden-input"></label>
```

But please notice that it's really not a proper way to swap text inside html element !

Comment: Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXdrPZ). You can see that the text just changes when the button is focused. But I'd also think this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Yup. This is what we can do with button element. If it's not required to use this element we can use a label with input for example. It would be better way. I will update my above answer in a moment.